# Javascript concat not working as expected - not merging

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, array-merge

I'm trying to merge values from a for loop, however it is not merging them into a single array, it is creating separate arrays?

I'm really new to Javascript, so am probably misunderstanding how to use the concat function. I have inserted a simplified version of my script below, I want the output to have all the values in a single array. can anyone help point me in the right direction please?

The code

```js
var fixed = document.getElementById('fixed');

var sections = document.getElementsByClassName('section');

for (i = 0; i < sections.length; i++) {
  var arr = [];

  arr = arr.concat(sections[i]);

  fixed.innerHTML = arr;
  console.log(arr);
}
```

```html
<div class="fixed" id="fixed"></div>
<div class="section"></div>
<div class="section"></div>
<div class="section"></div>
<div class="section"></div>
<div class="section"></div>
```

Comment: There's... quite a few things wrong here. Why are you using concat for individual elements? `sections[i]` is not an array, just use `arr.push(sections[i])`. Also, why are you setting the content of `fixed` on each iteration instead of only after you're done? Also, `innerHTML` is a text assignment, and `arr` is _not_ text. But also also, if you already have HTLM elements, putting them "in" another element is a matter of `thatElement.appendChild(htmlElement)`. Most _definitely_ not `.innerHTML`

Comment: `arr = sections`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare array before for loop, set `fixed.innerHtml` after and read about javascript scope.

```js
var fixed = document.getElementById('fixed');

var sections = document.getElementsByClassName('section');

var arr = [];

for (i = 0; i < sections.length; i++) {
  arr = arr.concat(sections[i]);
}

fixed.innerHTML = arr;
```

```html
<div class="fixed" id="fixed"></div>
<div class="section"></div>
<div class="section"></div>
<div class="section"></div>
<div class="section"></div>
<div class="section"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `arr` variable must be declared once, outside the loop, rather than re-declaring a new variable named `arr` each time around the loop.

In this way the results will accumulate in a single array.

```js
var fixed = document.getElementById('fixed');

var arr = [], sections = document.getElementsByClassName('section');

for (i = 0; i < sections.length; i++) {
  arr = arr.concat(sections[i]);

  fixed.innerHTML = arr;
  console.log(arr);
}
```

```html
<div class="fixed" id="fixed"></div>
<div class="section"></div>
<div class="section"></div>
<div class="section"></div>
<div class="section"></div>
<div class="section"></div>
```